# xlwt write excel sheet on the fly

Tags: python, xlwt

I am used to creating a spreadsheet in the following way:

```
    wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
    earnings_tab = wbk.add_sheet('EARNINGS')
    wbk.save(filepath)
```

Is there any way to not save to file to a filepath, and instead write it on-the-fly to a user who downloads the file? Or do I need to save it as a tmp file and then serve that to the user?

Comment: Django users: You can save to an HTTPResponse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To quote [the documentation for the `.save()` method of `xlwt`](https://xlwt.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=save#xlwt.Workbook.Workbook.save):

> It can also be a stream object with a write method, such as a
> `StringIO`, in which case the data for the excel file is written to the
> stream.

Modified example:

```
from io import StringIO  # instead of Python 2.x `import StringIO`

f = StringIO() # create a file-like object 

wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
earnings_tab = wbk.add_sheet('EARNINGS')

wbk.save(f) # write to stdout
```

Some may suggest you use `cStringIO` instead of `StringIO`, but be forewarned that `cStringIO` when last I checked does not properly handle Unicode.

### Important Update

*It's perhaps also worth noting that `StringIO` is replaced in Python 3 by `io`.*

> The StringIO and cStringIO modules are gone. Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO or io.BytesIO for text and data respectively.

[source](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)

So use:

```
from io import StringIO
# instead of import StringIO
```

Comment: You need to add io.seek(0) if you want to read (io.read()) from the file like object.

Answer (score 15):

this is what i use in Django:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=file.xls'
book.save(response)
return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class QueryToExcel(object):
def __init__(self, doc_name = 'doc_name'):
    #some set up stuff
    self.b_io = BytesIO()
    self.workbook = pd.ExcelWriter(self.b_io, engine='xlsxwriter')
    self.run() #fill in workbook with pandas dataframes
    self.workbook.save()

def get_workbook(self):
    return self.b_io.getvalue()


app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True 
@app.route('/pvh/', methods = ['GET'])
def get_workbook(self):
    return self.b_io.getvalue()
```